# Firebase 9, Remix: addDoc() returns "PERMISSION DENIED" error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, remix.run

I have a remix app using firebase & a firestore database.

The sign in works fine, the GET /documents as well (no rules for GET)

When I try to create a new document with `addDoc()` I get a `PERMISSION DENIED` error.

My rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow create, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email_verified && request.auth.token.email == 'my_email@gmail.com';
      allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Since I use Remix (SSR) I am initializing firebase in the client-side:

```
if (getApps().length === 0) {
  initializeApp({
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...",
    measurementId: "...",
  });
}
```

And I have `firebase-admin` in the server-side:

```
const serviceAccount = require("~/firebase-service-account.json");
serviceAccount.private_key_id = process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID;
serviceAccount.private_key = process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY;

if (getApps().length === 0) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  });
}
```

I use Google authentication in the client-side like this:

```
const submit = useSubmit();

const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  const { user } = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);

  if (user) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.set("user", JSON.stringify(user));
    submit(formData, { method: "post" });
  }
};
```

Then the `formData` is handled by my server-side code and create a sessionCookie with
`auth().createSessionCookie()`.

Everything works fine in my dashboard (only accessible by logged-in users, I am using `auth().verifySessionCookie()` to check that) until I create a new document with the
`addDoc` function from firebase 9. `auth` comes from `firebase-admin` package.

Here is the code I use:

```
const addDocument = async <T>(name: string, data: T): Promise<T> => {
  console.log(getAuth().currentUser) // null
  await addDoc(collection(db, name), data as Record<string, any>);

  cache().deleteEntry(name);

  return data;
};
```

When my write rule is set to `true` it works fine but when I put `request.auth != null` I have the permission error so I guess the problem is in the authentication part.

Comment: It's hard to say from the snippets shared, but it seems that `addDocument` runs before the user is signed in. I recommend adding some assertions/logging right before the call to `addDoc` to show the exact values that your rules depend on, like `console.log(getAuth().currentUser);`

Comment: Thanks for answering. The output is `null`, I feel that the client and server have a different value when doing `getAuth()`. The sign in part is client side and the `addDoc` is done server-side

Comment: Aha, I had missed that you're running this server-side. It's indeed quite possible/likely that the client-side auth state does not show up on the server. If you're for example using the Admin SDK there, it doesn't have the concept of a current user. --- Can you edit your question to show the updated code that logs the current user, and its output?

Comment: I updated the code and I confirm that this is the issue but I don't know how to solve it... If the sign in was done server-side it would work but I want to keep using the `GoogleAuthProvider` which is either by redirect or pop up so I must have the control on the client.

Or find a way to authenticate the user with the accessToken when creating the session just after sign in in the client side but I don't think that would be possible

Comment: That last snippet is using the regular JavaScript SDK, not the Admin SDK (as the Admin SDK doesn't have a `currentUser`). So if that code runs on the server, it is indeed (unfortunately) expected to not have a current user - as that value is only persisted on the client at the moment. Work is under way to add transparent client-to-server user persistence for some frameworks, but not yet for Remix.run that I know of. I'm checking for some more details though...

Comment: Thank you, I'll wait for news. In the meantime I switched to email/password authentication and called `signInWithEmailAndPassword` at server-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you may be using the Admin SDK on the server, that last code snippet is definitely a regular JavaScript SDK (as the Admin SDK doesn't have the concept of a `currentUser`). When you sign in the user on the client, that state does not automatically get transported to your server-side code.

The most common approach for accessing Firebase from the server until recently was to use the Admin SDK (which bypasses security rules) and perform any authorization checks in your application code.

You **can** use the regular JavaScript SDKs on the server, but you will have to ensure their sign-in state yourself. There is some [work in progress](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-framework-tools/blob/main/src/server/firebase-aware.ts) to do this automatically for Next.js and Angular Universal, but not yet for Remix.run. How these work (and what you'd have to do) is that they:

1. [Pass the sign-in information in session cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies)
2. [Verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) in the server-side code with Admin SDK.
3. If the verification succeeds, they [mint a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) for the user.
4. And then [sign in with that custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients) in the regular JavaScript SDK.

You'll need to ensure that you have a separate `FirebaseApp`/`Auth` instance for each user, and will probably want to set up a LRU cache for those to prevent having to perform that translation on each call.